# How to display my footer in every page when my report is more than one page

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-9

i have customized reports and i notice that when i have a report composed of more than one page my footer displays only in the first page however i want my footer displays in all pages . I'm using odoo 9. Any help please ? Here is my code

```
    <div class="footer" style="position:absolute;bottom:-1115px">

                    <div class="text-center" style="border-top: 1px solid black;">

                        <small>
                            <ul t-if="not company.custom_footer" class="list-inline">
                                <li t-if="company.phone">Phone:
                                    <span t-field="company.phone"/>
                                </li>


                                <li t-if="company.fax and company.phone">&amp;bull;</li>

                                <li t-if="company.fax">Fax:
                                    <span t-field="company.fax"/>
                                </li>


                                <li t-if="company.email and company.fax or company.email and company.phone">
                                    &amp;bull;
                                </li>


                                <t t-if="company.vat">TVA:
                                    <span t-field="company.vat"/>
                                </t>


                                <li t-if="company.company_registry">RC:
                                    <span t-field="company.company_registry"/>
                                </li>


                            </ul>
                        </small>


                        <small>
                            <ul class="list-inline">
                                <t t-set="nbr_page" t-value="1"/>
                                <li>Page:</li>
                                <t t-set="compteur" t-value="nbr_page+1"/>
                                <li>
                                    <span class="page"/>
                                    <t t-esc="nbr_page"/>
                                </li>
                                /
                                <t t-esc="nbr_page"/>
                                <li>
                                    <span class="topage"/>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </small>

                        <t t-set="nbr_page" t-value="1"/>
                        <t t-set="compteur" t-value="nbr_page+1"/>

                    </div>
                </div>
```